# How can I distribute the elements of one main array to another 2 arrays as balanced as possible?

Tags: java

I have a set of 2N players each one of which has a numerical indicator greater than zero that defines the quality as a player. From this set of players, I must create two teams of N players, A and B, such that the sum of the quality indicators of their components is as similar as possible.

I have this ready

This code that I did I realized that it does not solve the problem efficiently, because I open a team that will have A = (1,1,1,1,1,1) and the team B = (6), it is balanced but I do not know It is the best practice.

How can I create a code that can distribute force between teams, that is, be thrown to the best in both teams based on their difference until that team is better than the other.

```
int[] array = {8,8,9,6}; 
Team A={8,9}; 
Team B={8,6};
```

```
    class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) {

            int[] array = {8,8,9,6,1,7,1,3,7,5}; 

            //team strength A
                    int StrongA=0;
                    //team strength B
            int StrongB=0;

                    //Team A
            int[] A=new int[10];

            //Team B
            int[] B= new int[10];




            System.out.println("Quantity Teams: "+array.length);


            Arrays.sort(array);



            for(int i=0; i<(array.length)/2; i++) {

                //Team A
                A[i]=array[i];
                System.out.print("Team A:"+A[i]+" ");

                StrongA+=A[i];
            }
            System.out.println("Strong team A: "+fuerzaA);
            System.out.println();


          for(int i=5; i<10; i++) {

                //Team B
                B[i]=array[i];
                System.out.print("Team B:"+B[i]+" ");
                StrongB+=B[i];

            }
            System.out.println("//team strength B: "+StrongB);



            int dF= StrongB-StrongA;
            System.out.println("the df is: "+dF);


      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to test all possible teams and divide them so that the teams strengths are optimized. This is not a very fast method to divide the teams, but as long as the teams don't get to big it will be fast enough (to big would be player sized greater than 10_000 I think...).

An implementation in Java could look like this one:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TeamDistributor {

    private int[] players;
    private double optimalTeamStrength;

    private int[] bestTeam;//the best team found at the moment
    private double bestTeamStrengthDifference;//the difference between the current best team strength and the optimalTeamStrength

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] players = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
        TeamDistributor distributor = new TeamDistributor(players);
        int[][] teams = distributor.createTeams();//contains the indices of the teams
        printResults(distributor, players, teams);

        System.out.println("\n");
        players = new int[] {2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2};
        distributor = new TeamDistributor(players);
        teams = distributor.createTeams();
        printResults(distributor, players, teams);

        System.out.println("\n");
        players = new int[] {8, 8, 9, 6, 1, 7, 1, 3, 7, 5};
        distributor = new TeamDistributor(players);
        teams = distributor.createTeams();
        printResults(distributor, players, teams);
    }

    private static void printResults(TeamDistributor distributor, int[] players, int[][] teams) {
        int[][] strengths = distributor.getPlayersStrengthFromIndices(teams);

        System.out.println("Players: " + Arrays.toString(players));
        System.out.println("Team1 (indices): " + Arrays.toString(teams[0]));
        System.out.println("Team2 (indices): " + Arrays.toString(teams[1]));
        System.out.println("Team1 (individual strength): " + Arrays.toString(strengths[0]));
        System.out.println("Team2 (individual strength): " + Arrays.toString(strengths[1]));
        System.out.println("Team1 total strength: " + distributor.getTeamStrength(teams[0]));
        System.out.println("Team2 total strength: " + distributor.getTeamStrength(teams[1]));
    }

    public TeamDistributor(int[] players) {
        this.players = players;

        //calculate the total strength of all players combined
        double totalStrength = 0;
        for (int i : players) {
            totalStrength += i;
        }

        //calculate the optimal strength for a team
        optimalTeamStrength = totalStrength / 2;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the optimal teams and returns them as int-array (int[2][players.length/2])
     */
    public int[][] createTeams() {
        //assuming players.length is an even number
        int playersPerTeam = players.length / 2;
        //find the optimal team
        bestTeamStrengthDifference = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        createOptimalTeam(new int[playersPerTeam], 0);

        //the best team1 is in the global variable bestTeam
        //now create team2
        int[] team2 = new int[playersPerTeam];
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
            if (!containsPlayer(bestTeam, i)) {
                team2[index] = i;
                index++;
            }
        }

        //return team 1 and 2 as int[2][players/2]
        return new int[][] {bestTeam, team2};
    }

    /**
     * Create all teams and choose the one that is the closest to the optimalTeamStrength.
     */
    private void createOptimalTeam(int[] teamIndices, int playerIndex) {
        if (playerIndex >= teamIndices.length) {
            //no space for more players in this team -> test whether the current team is the best one yet
            int currentTeamStrength = getTeamStrength(teamIndices);
            double currentDifference = Math.abs(currentTeamStrength - optimalTeamStrength);
            if (currentDifference < bestTeamStrengthDifference) {
                bestTeam = teamIndices.clone();
                bestTeamStrengthDifference = currentDifference;
            }
        }
        else {
            //iterate through all possible players for the current index
            for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
                if (!containsPlayer(teamIndices, i)) {
                    //add a player to the current place
                    teamIndices[playerIndex] = i;
                    //add a player to the next place
                    createOptimalTeam(teamIndices, playerIndex + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether a team contains a player.
     */
    private boolean containsPlayer(int[] teamIndices, int playerIndex) {
        boolean contains = false;
        for (int i : teamIndices) {
            contains |= i == playerIndex;
        }
        return contains;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the total strength of a team.
     */
    public int getTeamStrength(int[] teamIndices) {
        int teamStrength = 0;
        for (int i : teamIndices) {
            teamStrength += players[i];
        }
        return teamStrength;
    }

    /**
     * Maps the players indices to the players strength.
     */
    public int[][] getPlayersStrengthFromIndices(int[][] playersIndices) {
        int[][] teamStrengths = new int[2][players.length / 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < teamStrengths.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < players.length / 2; j++) {
                teamStrengths[i][j] = players[playersIndices[i][j]];
            }
        }

        return teamStrengths;
    }
}
```

Here the main method is just for testing. I tested the following player strength arrays:

```
//just some test I created randomly
players1 = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
players2 = new int[] {2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2};
//the example from your question
players3 = new int[] {8, 8, 9, 6, 1, 7, 1, 3, 7, 5};
```

The output the algorithm creates is:

```
Players: [1, 2, 3, 4]
Team1 (indices): [1, 2]
Team2 (indices): [0, 3]
Team1 (individual strength): [2, 3]
Team2 (individual strength): [1, 4]
Team1 total strength: 5
Team2 total strength: 5


Players: [2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2]
Team1 (indices): [1, 2, 3, 8, 0]
Team2 (indices): [4, 5, 6, 7, 9]
Team1 (individual strength): [2, 3, 3, 2, 2]
Team2 (individual strength): [4, 4, 1, 1, 2]
Team1 total strength: 12
Team2 total strength: 12


Players: [8, 8, 9, 6, 1, 7, 1, 3, 7, 5]
Team1 (indices): [1, 2, 3, 4, 7]
Team2 (indices): [0, 5, 6, 8, 9]
Team1 (individual strength): [8, 9, 6, 1, 3]
Team2 (individual strength): [8, 7, 1, 7, 5]
Team1 total strength: 27
Team2 total strength: 28
```